# UIAnimator's UISnapBehavior possible with UIScrollview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uisnapbehavior

I am trying to figure out if I can use a UISnapBehavior from UIAnimator inside a UIScrollview to make scroll view's content snap to a point.  So far my findings have been lead to that this is impossible.

**What I am Trying to Achieve**

UIScrollView to 'snap' to certain point while the user is dragging the scroll view.  However, the scrolling has to resume from snapped position without the user having to lift the touch.

Apple seems to achieve this in Photo Editing in their iOS Photos App. (See screenshot below)

[image]

**What I Tried**

I tried to gain this behavior by attaching a UIPanGestureRecognizer to the scrollview and using it's velocity.  If the user is dragging towards the snapping point, scroll view will disable scrolling, animate to the snapping point, when done animating it will re-enable scrolling.

However, this lead to the issue where the user HAS TO LIFT the touch up after the drag and re-drag the scrollview.  Yet, Apple seems to have done it without having to lift the drag.

Comment: See the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48493973/1275014

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried to mimic iOS Photos app. Here is my logic:

```
// CALCULATE A CONTENT OFFSET FOR SNAPPING POINT 
let snapPoint = CGPoint(x: 367, y: 0)  

// CHANGE THESE VALUES TO TEST
let minDistanceToSnap = 7.0
let minVelocityToSnap = 25.0
let minDragDistanceToReleaseSnap = 7.0
let snapDuringDecelerating = false
```

This kind of scrolling needs 3 stages

```
enum SnapState {
case willSnap
case didSnap
case willRelease
}
```

1. `willSnap:` Default state. Decide when to snap. Compare `contentOffset distance from SnapPoint with minDistanceToSnap` and `scrollview velocity with minVelocityToSnap`. Change to `didSnap` state.
2. `didSnap:` Manually `setContentOffset` to a provided `contextOffset(snapPoint)`. Calculate `dragDistance` on `scrollView`. If user drag more than a certain distance (`minDragDistanceToReleaseSnap`) change to `willRelease` state.
3. `willRelease:` Change to `willSnap` state again if `distance scroll from snapPoint` is more than `minDistanceToSnap`.

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        switch(snapState) {
            case .willSnap:
                let distanceFromSnapPoint = distance(between: scrollView.contentOffset, and: snapPoint)
                let velocity = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.velocityInView(view)
                let velocityDistance = distance(between: velocity, and: CGPointZero)
                if distanceFromSnapPoint <= minDistanceToSnap && velocityDistance <= minVelocityToSnap && (snapDuringDecelerating || velocityDistance > 0.0) {
                    startSnapLocaion = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.locationInView(scrollView)
                    snapState = .didSnap
                }
            case .didSnap:
                scrollView.setContentOffset(snapPoint, animated: false)
                var dragDistance = 0.0
                let location = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.locationInView(scrollView)
                dragDistance = distance(between: location, and: startSnapLocaion)
                if dragDistance > minDragDistanceToReleaseSnap  {
                    startSnapLocaion = CGPointZero
                    snapState = .willRelease
                }
            case .willRelease:
                let distanceFromSnapPoint = distance(between: scrollView.contentOffset, and: snapPoint)
                if distanceFromSnapPoint > minDistanceToSnap {
                    snapState = .willSnap
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Helper function

```
func distance(between point1: CGPoint, and point2: CGPoint) -> Double {
    return Double(hypotf(Float(point1.x - point2.x), Float(point1.y - point2.y)))
}
```

Made a demo project on Github: https://github.com/rishi420/SnapDrag

Note: Project made with Xcode 7.2. You may need to change a bit to compile.

Comment: Any reason you're using the custom function `distance(between:and:)` instead of `CGPoint.distance(to:)`?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth `CGPoint` has a `distance(to:)` function? I didn't know that.

Comment: It's not a class func but you can do `pointA.distance(to: pointB)`

Answer (score 1):

Don't add the UIPanGestureRecognizer directly to the UIScrollView. Rather add it to a container view, then in the selector, set the UIScrollView contentOffset manually.

Disable interaction on the UIScrollView itself, or use the delegate, to prevent interaction directly with the scroll view.